# valid or invalid GROUP BY query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

```
 SELECT S2.A
 FROM S1, S2
 WHERE S1.A = S2.A
 GROUP BY S1.A
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Is this a valid query?

Because from what i understand, whatever is in your select clause has to be in your group by clause, but this query does not follow it.

However, by looking at this query, it does make sense to me beacuse your are selecting the A attribute values from S2 such that S1.A = S2.A whereby the number of that particular A value of S1 has more than 1 records.

Comment: You need to group according to what you select, so if you selected `S2.A` you can't group by `S1.A`...

Comment: @alfasin "bad thing", but this is not true in mysql...

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus my bad - I didn't notice the `mysql` tag. BTW, it *is* true for PLSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, you don't NEED to have whatever is not aggregated in your select clause in the `group by` when you use an aggregation IN MYSQL (so your assumption is ANSIly correct, but not really for mysql).

But as `S1.A = S2.A`, why don't you select `S1.A` ?

By the way, you should use `JOIN`, and I would write the query this way :

```
SELECT S1.A
FROM S1
INNER JOIN S2 on S1.A = S2.A
GROUP BY S1.A
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```